# Macro concatenating strings + number + date

Tags: vba, excel

I need to concatenate few cells values into one cell that will always be next to the concatenated ones. Here is the example:

[image: My excel sheet]

There will always be 4 main columns with data and the 5th one "Wynik" will be used to concatenate the values from the 4 cells in the same row. So for example the final result in each row (in "Wynik column) will be "REG-15_S1_2018-01-20_12333"

I want to create macro for it to do it instantly because there will be thousends of records in each columns but I didnt found any example for it, neither I'm expert in VBA... Do u have any solution how to do it or any popular macro that can be used?

I will be thankful for any help.

Alex

Comment: You don't need a macro for this. Just use `=A2&"_"&B2&"_"&C2&"_"&D2` and fill down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim data As Variant

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        data = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 4).Offset(1).Value
    End With

    ReDim wynik(1 To UBound(data)) As Variant

    Dim i As Variant
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        data(i, 3) = Format(data(i, 3), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        wynik(i) = Join(Application.index(data, i, 0), "_")
    Next
    Range("E2").Resize(UBound(data)).Value = Application.Transpose(wynik)
End Sub
```

Comment: Fenomenal work! One more thing, can u add to this the conversion from "Data" column which contains various data formats to format "yyyy-mm-dd" into final "Wynik" column?

Comment: you are welcome... if I solved your _original_ question you may consider marking this answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: Thanks again, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=A2&"_"&B2&"_"&text(C2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"_"&D2
'optional for leading zeroes in column D
=A2&"_"&B2&"_"&text(C2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"_"&text(D2, "00000")
```

Comment: Thanks you, aprreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

In the column of the combined cells, put the formula:

```
=A2&B2&C2&D2
```

Copy the formula down in the column.